# Input type="text" default value cant able to change in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a requirement that, i have one html text field initially it should have a default value as `0`. But, later point of time i want to change the value of text box ( in ReactJS ).

Am not able to change the default value. Please find my reactjs code for the same.

```
<input name="discount" type="text" id="header_discount" step="0.01"  maxLength="5" min="0" max="100"  value={ this.state.item.discount ? this.state.item.discount : this.state.item.discount = "0" }  className="form-control" onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />
```

Comment: check this https://codesandbox.io/s/7jj8z6o33j @Karthikeyan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use default value prop:

```
<input  defaultValue={0} name="discount" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Set default state on constructor after that change value using handlechange function. your ternary statement on input is not correct.